# Capture scrolling of child view controller

Tags: uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` - `WSProfileViewController`. This VC has a `headerView`, and then a `containerView` that loads one of three `tableViewController` as a `childViewController` of `WSProfileViewController`. I want to be able to scroll the `headerView` up whenever the current `tableView` scrolls up, as if it was a `headerView` of the `tableView` itself.

In the main VC, `WSProfileViewController`, I made it a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implemented `scrollViewDidScroll`, but it's never called. It currently has no connection the the `scrollViews` of the child `tableViews`.

*Each child `tableViewController` has different data models, and are classes used elsewhere, so I want to keep them as is and just load them as children.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't want to alter any of the code for the `child view controllers` but I'm pretty sure there isn't any way for the parent to directly capture child scrolling unless I make it the `delegate` of the `child tableviews`, but I can't do that because each `child view controller` needs to be their own tableview's delegate.

Correct me if I'm missing something.

What I did was send a notification from each child's `scrollViewDidScroll` method like so:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSDictionary *scrollViewInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:scrollView  forKey:@"someKey"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someNotificationName" object:nil userInfo:scrollViewInfo];

}
```

And then simply observe that in the parent:

```
#pragma mark - Notifications
- (void)registerForNotifications {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(childScrollViewDidScroll:) name:@"someNotificationName" object:nil];
}

- (void)childScrollViewDidScroll:(NSNotification *)note {

    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[note userInfo] valueForKey:@"someKey"];

    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;    

    CGRect headerFrame = self.headerView.frame;

    headerFrame.origin.y = -scrollOffset;

    self.headerView.frame = headerFrame;

}
```

It's scrolling the header view on the device without lag, so at least for the moment I'm satisfied.

Comment: I don't think that this will perform that fine-grainly. As when the users scrolls rapidly, you can't expect notification to be observed as smoothly as the scroll.